# Openshift Zend Server - Access to Zend Server user interface returns a blank page

Tags: php, openshift, zend-server

When I try to access to my Zend Server user interface in OpenShift I get a blank page, any error message nor fail nor javascript error, etc. Is a gear two or three days old only.

I have reboot the gear and it happens the same.

From the Openshift Forum I am redirected here.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: They will be pleased over at Zend with that title

Comment: Right, thank you! Sorry Zend people!

Comment: What errors show up in your error logs? you can view them with the rhc tail command.